# what's the difference between %n and %f in rsync's --out-format?

Tags: rsync

I'm parsing rsync's output and would like to be certain that I know what input I get. I'm wondering whether to use `--out-format '%i %n'` or `--out-format '%i %f'`, but what's the difference, apart from the trailing slash on directories?

`man rsyncd.conf` says under `log format`:

- %n the filename (short form; trailing "/" on dir)
- %f the filename (long form on sender; no trailing "/")

– what's the difference between "short form" and "long form"?

Answer (score 1):

https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=log.c;h=b145ee1d893904835cd3c9276ec7c9c6fbaf13f3;hb=HEAD#l589 seems to be the source.

%n is the simpler version, and just prints the filename relative to the destination, so if you call rsync with source argument `a/b`, then it will print e.g. `b/somefile`.

%f prints the filename relative to the source if `am_sender`, so if the source argument was `a/b`, it will print e.g. `a/b/somefile`. If `am_daemon`, it seems to prepend the module name, though I've never tried that. It additionally calls `clean_fname`, which seems to remove superfluous double slashes or dots from the source (e.g. if you call it with `a//./b` it still prints `a/b/somefile`).